# How to Populate textbox with cookie value when check remember me in mvc 5.0 razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing asp.net MVC 5.0 application, I have created login page i have remember me check box to store values in to cookie.

below is code is to save value into cookie

```
     bool remember = Convert.ToBoolean(fc["chkrememberme"].Split(',')[0]);

        if (remember == true)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Login");
            cookie.Values.Add("useremail", fc["authemail"]);
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
```

Now I want populate Useremail textbox with cookie value if exists in view.

how to resolve my problem .

Comment: Why woudn't you consider creating persistent Login Cookie and auto login user if user select "rememberme" check box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Set Cookie value in either `model` or `ViewBag`

```
Viewbag.Email =   Request.Cookies["useremail"];
```

OR

```
Viewbag.Email =   Request.Cookies["useremail"].toString();
```

OR

```
Viewbag.Email =   Request.Cookies["useremail"].Value;
```

Thanks